# Can you simplify (or approximate) $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{N-1}n \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} e^{-\frac{n}{2(n+1)}\lambda}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, sumsets

Let $\binom x y$ be the binomial coefficient. I am trying to get a better understanding of the sum
$$
f(N,\lambda)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}n\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} e^{-\frac{n}{2(n+1)}\lambda}
$$
as a function of $\lambda$ and $N$ without having to plot it for all possible values.

Do you know of a way to simplify it or approximate it? Although I'd rather obtain an approximation for positive $\lambda$ and $N$, an asymptotic approximation for $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$ or $N\rightarrow\infty$, or even an upper-bound would be helpful too.

Here is an equivalent expression:
$$
f(N,\lambda)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\binom N n(-1)^{n-1} e^{-\frac{n-1}{2n}\lambda}.
$$

In my opinion, this sum could be easily simplified if the exponential term would have an argument that was not a rational function $\frac{n}{n+1}$ or $\frac{n-1}{n}$. I have not found a way in the literature to deal with it.

Comment: It would help if you explain a bit more what properties of $f(N,\lambda)$ you're interested in. E.g., are you interested in the asymptotic behavior for $N$ large, or also for small $N$? For which range of $\lambda$'s? Do you need a sharp estimate, or will a bound or a rough qualitative understanding be enough? Etc.

Comment: Hi @dan-romik . I edited the question.

Answer (score 9):

The factor $\exp(-n\lambda/(2n+2))$ probably precludes significant
simplification of $f(N,\lambda)$, but one can still construct
an integral representation that shows $f(N,\lambda) > 0$ for all
positive $N$ and $\lambda$, and makes it possible to estimate the sum.

The idea is to find, given $\lambda$, a representation of
$\exp(-n\lambda/(2n+2)) \, / \, (n+1)$ as a linear combination of
exponentials $\exp(-cn)$ for which the sum can be evaluated
in closed form as a binomial expansion.  In other words,
we want to write $\exp(-n\lambda/(2n+2)) \, / \, (n+1)$ as a Laplace transform.
We use the definite integral formula
$$
\int_0^\infty I_0(\sqrt x) e^{-ax} \, dx = \frac1a \exp \frac1{4a},
$$
where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function
$I_0(z) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty (z/2)^{2m} / m!^2$.  Writing
$$
e^{-\frac{n}{2(n+1)}\lambda} = e^{-\lambda/2} e^{\frac\lambda{2(n+1)}},
$$
we soon find
$$
f(N,\lambda) = \frac{e^{-\lambda/2}}{2\lambda}
  \int_0^\infty I_0(\sqrt x) \left[
    \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (-1)^n {N-1 \choose n} e^{-\frac{n+1}{2\lambda}x}
  \right] \, dx
$$
in which the bracketed sum is $\exp(-x/2\lambda)$ times a binomial expansion:
$$
f(N,\lambda) = \frac{e^{-\lambda/2}}{2\lambda}
  \int_0^\infty I_0(\sqrt x) \, e^{-\frac{x}{2\lambda}}
    \left(1 - e^{-\frac{x}{2\lambda}} \right)^{N-1}
  \, dx \, .
$$
The integrand is nonnegative, so $f(N,\lambda) > 0$ as claimed.
Moreover, its size can be estimated for any given $N,\lambda$
by determining at what $x$ the integrand is maximized and how rapidly
it decays from this maximum.

Comment: Hi @noam-d-elkies

Impressive, you actually reverted how I got to my expression. I departed from the integral form. the advantage about the sum is that is easy to evaluate numerically more than the integral in my opinion.

You mention, the the integral could be estimated from the maximum and decay of the integrand. Could you be more precise? Perhaps you would fit a Gaussian curve?

Comment: @Noam: Without the factor that's raised to the power $N-1$, the integral evaluates to 1 so it is a probability density function.  I wonder if it is a studied distribution as it seems quite nice.  It has mean $\lambda(\lambda+2)$ and variance $4\lambda^2(\lambda+1)$.

Comment: @brendan-mckay : This expression is the probability that a noncentral chi-square random variable of parameter $\lambda$ and 2 degrees of freedom is larger than $N-1$ chi-squares random variables of 2 degrees of freedom as well.

Comment: So answering your question. It is the probability density function of the noncentral chi-square.

Answer (score 3):

for $|\lambda|\ll 1$ you might expand as

$$Nf(N,\lambda)=1+\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda\,(H_N-1)+{\rm order}\,(\lambda^2)$$

with $H_N$ the harmonic number.

For $\lambda$ large a reasonable approximation is

$$f(N,\lambda)\approx 1-\tfrac{1}{2}(N-1)e^{-\lambda/4},\;{\rm for}\;\lambda\,{\gtrsim}\, 1,N$$

Comment: Hi @carlo-beenakker . Thanks for the asymptotic approximation. Do you know of a similar expression for $\lambda$ large and real?

Comment: I see. For large $\lambda$ you took the two first terms of the sum.